# Subclass specific associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do something like this in rails but I feel I'm heading for trouble.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class BankAccount < Account
    has_many :users
end

class PaypalAccount < Account
    has_many :users, :limit 1
end
```

Is this the way to go?

And if yes, can I still do this in the User model safely?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me more logical the opposite direction:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class BankAccount < Account
end

class PaypalAccount < Account
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  has_one :paypal_account
end
```

Comment: Well, it makes sense with the names I took (my mistake) but it does not. My question was more rhetoric than the example shows. :)